# Regex find a fixed number of words between two strings

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
    String phrase = "higher than <> expected";
```

`<>` stands for a number of words that does not exceed 5.

My regex below returns infinite number of matches which is not helpful as I don't want more than 5 matches.

```
String regex = "(?i)higher than(.*?)expected(?-i)";
```

Comment: What app/language implementation are you using?

Comment: Do you want all the words that are of length 5 between `higher than` and `expected` ? Say for example: `higher than foooooo bar  expected`. It should return `bar` only? Since `foooooo` has length more than 5.

Comment: @AbsoluteƵERØ I'm using Java.

Comment: @NeverHopeless the length of the word doesn't really matter. The number of words between "higher than" and "expected" should be no more than 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following regex should work for you:

```
(?<=higher than\s)((?:\w+\s*){1,5})(?=\s+expected)
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/EUDywHXmGm

Answer (score 1):

You can match number of occurrences with regexes, although you might need extended regexes.

`\d{1-3}` would match 1 to 3 digits.

You can also use non-greedy matching, because the problem with your current implementation is that `(.*?)` matches everything. For example, `<.+?>` will match an XML tag. The `?` after the `+` makes it lazy.

Here is a good [reference site for regexes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/examples.html).

Answer (score 1):

Look behind and Look around are suitable here but as an alternative you can also use this one with the help of non-capturing groups.

You should also consider multiple leading and trailing spaces after `higher than` and before `expected`.

```
(?:higher than\s*)((?:\w+\s*){0,5})(?:\s*expected)
```

Comment: didn't think about leading trailing and spaces, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 0):

If the words may also occur in reverse order, we need to specify the opposite pattern as well:

```
\b(?:(?:higher than)\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}?(?:expected)|(?:expected)\W+(?:\w+\W+){0,5}?(?:higher than))\b
```